# Add geom_vline using function where xintercept comes from a vector not ggplot data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to draw multiple verical lines on a ggplot, which positions come from a separate vector.

```
library(ggplot2)

carats <- c(2.5, 0.1)

ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat)) +
  geom_histogram() +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = carats[1]), col = "black", linetype = "dotted", size = 0.5) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = carats[2]), col = "black", linetype = "dotted", size = 0.5)
```

Adding them one by one works, but I would like to avoid such approach add use `draw_vline` instead:

```
hist <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat)) + geom_histogram() 

draw_vline <- function(histogram, line_value){
  hist + geom_vline(aes(xintercept = line_value), col = "black", linetype = "dotted", size = 0.5)
}

draw_vline(hist, carats[1])
```

This gives me error:

`Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'line_value' not found`

How can I specify my function to work with external vector which isn't in ggplot env?

Comment: `geom_vline(xintercept = carats, col = "black", linetype = "dotted", size = 0.5)`

Comment: This gives `Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (53940): xintercept`

Comment: Nope, it absolutely does not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`aes()` is for mapping data *from columns in the data frame*. You don't have a data frame and the `_vline`/`_hline/`/`_abline` even show that the default use of 
`xintercept`, `yintercept`, `slope` & `intercept` is *outside* `aes()`. This works fine in `aes()`, too, provided you supplied the call with `data` set, but you didn't.

```
library(ggplot2)

carats <- c(2.5, 0.1)

ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat)) +
  geom_histogram() +
  geom_vline(xintercept = carats, col = "black", linetype = "dotted", size = 0.5)
```

[image]

Comment: That's great and so easy! Thanks so much!